# Editing Files In a Pods In Kubernetes

Tags: ubuntu, containers, kubernetes

I am trying to edit a file in my pod from my local machine using **kubectl exec**, but it is not working!

Example:
Suppose I am working on Ubuntu and having a pod named "Pod1", I want to edit a file named /lists inside Pod1. I am doing this
***kubectl exec Pod1 cat /lists >> "HELLO"*** 
but it is not working, please how to solve this kind of problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `cat` a local file over. One way is to store the file in a BASH variable first before sending it over

```
lists=$(cat /lists); kubectl exec Pod1 "echo $lists >> HELLO"
```

But this isn't a great way either. Are you attempting to debug the app or to automate some process by writing to a file this way? If it's the latter, may I suggest using a ConfigMap instead?

Comment: I just want to be able to configure a running pod from my local machine! Will ConfigMap do the trick?

Comment: What do you mean with "configure"? Do you need to configure your application running inside the pod? Like injecting environment variables?

Comment: @hassan-shaitou Is this a permanent config or a temporary runtime config? Either way, the k8s kosher way is for the app to read off a ConfigMap. If this config occasionally changes, write your app to monitor the config file and reload when it changes. If you have no control over how the app works but it's ok restart the Pod, then update the ConfigMap and kill the existing Pod. You have to elaborate on your Ops before a real suggestion can be made.